# Making a launch screen using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, launch-screen

Apple's [recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/launch-screen/) is that an app launch screen not be a logo or something artistic, but instead look like a static version of the app's opening screen in order to create the impression of responsiveness.  I want to try to do that, but my the challenge is that my opening screen was created entirely with SwiftUI.  It would be a huge pain to try to recreate my SwiftUI screen using storyboards.  Is there a way to make a SwiftUI-based launch screen for an app to replace the LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Comment: Just take a screenshot of your app's opening screen.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make a SwiftUI-based launch screen for an app to replace the LaunchScreen.storyboard?

No. A launch screen is not based in any programming language or code. By definition, when the launch screen appears, none of your code has run yet.

Note however that a full reconstruction of your opening screen is not at all necessary. A background of the right color, and, say, a navigation bar if the app has one, is quite sufficient.

Comment: @Aswath It answers it with the first word. It's a yes-no question, and the answer is No.